# How to get specific data from hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I need some  explanation about below scenario

Scenario:-->
     Suppose there is complete records of each human being in the world in a file of 1000PB, we transferred that file into HDFS ( let's say Reflection_factor=  9 bl_size=128MB ) and that file divide into 'n' number of blocks.

Suppose Client asked us to search a particular person with some unique  constraints (Key). Lets assume that the person's data is in the nth block.

My question is how MapReduce function will work in this case? is it directly read the nth block or it will read first node to nth node?

Comment: How would HDFS know which fragment has the data? You would have to create a M/R job that would split the 1000PB in, say, 1 million jobs, then execute them *all*, and one job (you don't know upfront which!) will emit one row for the match.

Answer (score 2):

`HDFS` is good sequential access while `HBase` is good for

- single random selects
- range scans by key
- variable schema

So as suggested by @WinnieNicklaus you should look into loading the data into HBase if you are looking for random access.

Answer (score 1):

This use case is what [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/) was designed for.